Failed to create domain from /etc/libvirt/qemu/vps.xml error: internal error: Failed to start QEMU : libvirt kvm: Exec format error
Had This error:
Failed to create domain from /etc/libvirt/qemu/vps.xml error: internal error: Failed to start QEMU : libvirt kvm: Exec format error
The fix for me was to reinstall:
apt-get reinstall qemu-kvm
Hope it helps someone, thanks
https://www.ccp.care
The fix for me was to reinstall:
apt-get reinstall qemu-kvm
